# How can I determine which column has been sorted in a DataGridView when the SortMode is Automatic

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

Winforms DataGridView

The SortedColumn is always null (expected when SortMode is Automatic) and the bindingSource sort property is always blank.

Comment: is this Winform DataGridView

Comment: Yes.. I will update the question, thanks

Comment: What is your `DataSource` and/or setup? Doing a simple test of binding the `DataGridView.DataSource` to a `DataTable`, clicking on any column header to sort that column, then using a `Button.Click` event to debug the `DataGridView.SortedColumn` showed the correct column (*not* `null`).

Comment: Ok, thank you.. I created another basic datagrid, a couple of tables with a relationship and same datasource and I can get the SortedColumn now from that.. BUT comparing the simple project to the more complex one I can't seem to find what is causing the behavior of the Sorted column to be null still in the current complex project - I will continue to trawl through the code looking for potential causes.

Comment: If you can find the shortest example code to reproduce the problem, please edit it into your question so we can better help.

Comment: I have spent the better part of a day trying to isolate which part of the code may be the source.. no luck yet, running out of ideas :)

Comment: I had multiple DataGridViews with similar names on a TabPage. The problem was that I was testing the sort on the wrong DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am not wrong DataGridView supports single column sorting,
and you can get the sorted column name by

```
var sortedCol = dataGridView1.SortedColumn.DataPropertyName;
```

Comment: There is something wrong with my project that is preventing the sorted column from being set. I am not certain what circumstances would do that though.